# Ошибка при замене спец.символов

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который отлично отрабатывает, если в объекте с перечнем подлежащих замене символов не добавлять "специальные". Пример ниже вернет, как и задумано: `front%end`.

```js
let sortArr = {
  " ": "-",
  "-": "%",
  "!": "i33",
};
                
let str = 'front-end'


let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(sortArr).join("|"),"gi");
    str = str.replace(re, function(matched) {
        console.log('matched ', matched);
        return sortArr[matched.toLowerCase()];
    });
    
alert(str);
```

Тот же пример, но добавим, например, `$`:

```js
let sortArr = {
  " ": "-",
  "-": "%",
  "!": "i33",
  "$": "i36",
};
                
let str = 'front-end'


let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(sortArr).join("|"),"gi");
    str = str.replace(re, function(matched) {
        console.log('matched ', matched);
        return sortArr[matched.toLowerCase()];
    });
    
alert(str);
```

Результат: `front%endundefined`. Что я делаю не так?
Ссылка на песочницу [здесь](https://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/ExVPJBK?editors=0010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` - специальный знак "конец строки". Вот он у вас и пытается заменить конец строки через... `matched`, который уже не является символом `$`

Первая попытка `\\$`, уже получается исключить подмену конца строки, но не прокатывает, если нужно реально заменить знак `$`:

```js
let sortArr = {
  " ": "-",
  "-": "%",
  "!": "i33",
  "\\$": "i36",
};

let str = 'front end $$';

let re = new RegExp( Object.keys(sortArr).join("|"), "gi");
str = str.replace(re, function(matched) {
  console.log('matched ', matched);
  return sortArr[matched.toLowerCase()];
});

console.log(str);
```

Попытка 2: в строке для RegExp, перед всеми спец-симвлами подставить `\`:

`.replace(/(\$|\?|\+)/g, "\\$1")` — в replace, в заменяемой строке `$1` ссылается на совпадение внутри первой группы захвата (то, что внутри скобок).

```js
let sortArr = {
  " ": "-",
  "-": "%",
  "!": "i33",
  "$": "i36",
  "?": "999",
  "|": "Mooo...",
  "+": "+++",
};

let str = '||front end $$?+';

let keys = Object.keys(sortArr).join("|")
            .replace(/(\$|\?|\+)/g, "\\$1")
            .replace(/(^|\|)\|(\||$)/, "$1\\|$2");
            
let reg = new RegExp(keys, "gi");

console.log(reg);

str = str.replace(reg, function(match) {
  return sortArr[match];
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что слеш тоже заслешить нужно `.replace(/\$/, "\\\$")`. Могу ошибаться, но проверил - работает.

Comment: В том то и дело, что у меня гораздо более широкий перечень таких символов, в том числе, наверное, все из числа "специальных". А в регулярках не силён.

Comment: @UModeL для строки же нет разницы, `$` или `\$` ... съест "\" и ничего не будет... поэтому работает и \\$, и \\\$ ... в обоих случаях на выходе получается `\$`

Comment: @Игорь немного изменил replace)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, спасибо за помощь. Есть еще небольшой нюанс - что, если менять надо и `|`?

Comment: @Игорь `.replace(/(^|\|)\|(\||$)/, "$1\\|$2")` — `|`, который идет после `^` начала строки или другого `|` и заканчивается `$` концом строки или другим `|`

Answer (score 0):

В regular expressions, символ доллара, это специальный символ, который обозначает конец текста.

Чтобы искать сам знак доллара в тексте, нужно его «escape», то есть вместо «$» использовать «\$».